# Difference between K&R and ANSI function outputs

Tags: c

I ran the following code, and found some strange output.

```
int
mean_ansi (int num1, int num2)
{
  printf ("In %s\n", __FUNCTION__);
  printf ("num1,num2 is %d,%d\n", num1, num2);
  return (num1 + num2) / 2;
}

int
mean_K_and_R (num1, num2)
     int num1, num2;
{
  printf ("In %s\n", __FUNCTION__);
  printf ("num1,num2 is %d,%d\n", num1, num2);
  return (num1 + num2) / 2;
}


int
main ()
{
  int i = 6;
  double f = 1.0;

  printf ("In %s\n", __FUNCTION__);
  printf ("[f,i] = [%f,%d]\n", f, i);

  /* deliberate mistakes */
  mean_ansi (f, i);
  mean_K_and_R (f, i);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

In main

[f,i] = [1.000000,6]

In mean_ansi

num1,num2 is 1,6

In mean_K_and_R

num1,num2 is 0,1072693248

Can anyone explain this behavior.

I saw the assembly but could not make out much.

Is there a difference in the way function arguments are pushed on the stack in both these syntaxes?

Comment: Good question (and good reason to definitively bury K&R declarations)

Comment: You could sensibly accept an answer to this question — and to quite a lot of the other questions you've asked and received answers for.  When you've thought about it, you can flag this comment as 'no longer needed'.

Answer (score 4):

Dan Olson had the right idea, and Slartibartfast explained where the values com from:

The definition of `mean_K_and_R()` is treated as if it were defined like this

```
int mean_K_and_R();
```

ie the function takes any arguments and doesn't do any conversion aside from the default argument promotion.

If the cdecl calling convention is used, this means `mean_K_and_R(f, i)` will first push `i` to the stack, then the higher bits of `f` and then the lower bits of `f`.

But the function thinks it took two integer arguments, meaning `num1` will now refer to the lower bits of `f` and `num2` to the higher bits of `f`.

Comment: This is probably aggravated by the fact that the arguments are used with printf, which does no type checking.  What would happen when they're used in the expression return (num1 + num2) / 2?  The function thinks they're ints, will it try to promote from double to int?

Comment: @Dan: this has nothing to do with `printf()`: the compiler has already 'lost' the type information, ie there won't be any conversion done even in arithmetic expressions; the bit pattern of the double is interpreted as two integers because of it's particular position in the stack

Comment: @Dan: if you know C++, think something along the lines of `reinterpret_cast<int [2]>(f)` where the resulting array holds `num1` and `num2`

Answer (score 2):

I did some digging and found a [thread](http://bytes.com/groups/c/215340-k-r-style-function-declarations-good-bad) indicating that K&R style function declarations don't create a prototype, so without a separate prototype the compiler is free to treat the arguments incorrectly if it desires.

I'm not sure how true this is, you could probably verify it by inserting a prototype quickly and seeing if the functions generate the same values.

In any case K&R style declarations are very outdated, as I'm sure you know, and should probably be avoided.  If anything your problem is an example of that.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that in the first case, there wan an implicit conversion of `double` to `int`. In a second one, 64 bits representing 1.0 were interpreted as two integers. Number 1072693248 is represented binnary as

```
00111111111100000000000000000000
```

but if you take a look at [this page](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html), you'll see that this is actually an upper half of double representation of number 1. The first 0 is sign, 01111111111 is exponent and rest of zeros are an upper bits of fraction. Only thing I don't get is where the 1 for fraction went? Having said all this I would expect the output to be 1,1072693248.

Comment: the firt bit of the fractional part is always 1 (as long as the values are not subnormal), ie there's no need to store it